# Combobox's populated from string array are duplicating

Tags: c#, combobox

my comboboxes are populating correctly, but once I select a value in 1 of the 4 boxes, all boxes take the same value.

culturesListNames is info from a txt file, that I want to apply to 4 comboboxes

My code:

```
String[] culturesListNames1 = new String[300];
String[] culturesListNames2 = new String[300];
String[] culturesListNames3 = new String[300];
String[] culturesListNames4 = new String[300];

culturesListNames1 = culturesListNames;
culturesListNames2 = culturesListNames;
culturesListNames3 = culturesListNames;
culturesListNames4 = culturesListNames;

BindingSource theBindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
theBindingSource1.DataSource = culturesListNames1;

BindingSource theBindingSource2 = new BindingSource();
theBindingSource2.DataSource = culturesListNames2;

BindingSource theBindingSource3 = new BindingSource();
theBindingSource3.DataSource = culturesListNames3;

BindingSource theBindingSource4 = new BindingSource();
theBindingSource4.DataSource = culturesListNames4;

comboBox1.DataSource = theBindingSource1.DataSource;
comboBox2.DataSource = theBindingSource2.DataSource;
comboBox3.DataSource = theBindingSource3.DataSource;
comboBox4.DataSource = theBindingSource4.DataSource;`
```

Comment: Where is culturesListNames defined? My immediate thoughts are the lines where you assign culturesListNames1 to 4 to the same object. They are all pointing to culturesListNames in memory.

Comment: Whatever type `culturesListNames` is, you assign the **same** instance to all four `cultureListNamesX` variables. You should clone or copy the data from the `culturesListNames`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is defined by Wheels73 and Michael. Either you have to copy the data or make it's clone as follow:

[image]
[image]